# LDA and QDA main concepts

Tags: discriminant-analysis

I've been studying LDA and QDA main concepts and already can implement those algorithms, but I'm not good at understanding the theory of this technique. Textbooks and Google gives me some properties and ideas about them, but LDA and QDA are still not absolutely clear for me. I already know that LDA uses Gaussian density, has linear boundaries and common covariance matrix; inputs should be conditionally independent. QDA is used when covariance matrices are different.

But can you please explain me (in simple words) why does the equation linear discriminant function looks this way and when should we use LDA and QDA?

Comment: Pardon me, it looks unnatural when somebody says he can implement a statistical analysis algorithm and says he doesn't understand ideas of it and when to use it. Have a look at the Q/A about LDA and QDA on this site (search). If it won't help, please tell why.

Comment: Coding the solution given definitions and formula doesn't mean full understanding of the technique, I've met many people, who can implement the solution but actually don't know why it works I haven't found the exaplnation of the linear discriminant function on the site, unfortunately.